# Unexpected exit from windows batch section

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am developing a batch file to collect websphere products information, it seems to work fine except for some cases.

For some reason under some circumstances versionInfo.bat -maintenancePackages is called but the following code (check for manageprofiles.bat), it seems like it's returning from the :check section after calling versionInfo.

My Windows batch writing skills are very rusty, other improvements are welcome.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set tmpfile=%TEMP%\tmpdone.txt

echo. > %tmpfile%
For /F "eol= delims=| tokens=13" %%a in (%windir%\vpd.properties) Do (
set check=%%a
call :check
)
goto eof

:check
Set skip=No
For /F "eol= delims=|" %%a in (%tmpfile%) Do (
if "%%a" == "%check%" set skip=YES
)

if %skip% == YES goto eof
echo %check%>>%tmpfile%
if exist "%check%\bin\versionInfo.bat" "%check%\bin\versionInfo.bat" -maintenancePackages
echo %check%\bin\manageprofiles.bat
if exist "%check%\bin\manageprofiles.bat" "%check%\bin\manageprofiles.bat" -listProfiles
goto eof

:del
echo Done
del %tmpfile%

:eof
```

Comment: Do you have any exit call in your versionInfo.bat? This might trigger an exit from the whole script if you are not using exit /b.

Comment: I don't have any control over the contents/exit of versionInfo.bat, so yes, it might be doing an exit. I am not sure I understand why the exit code of a called batch would interrupt the current section.

Comment: Your question pointed me in the right direction, I need to "call" the versionInfo.bat to prevent it from exiting the current section.

Comment: Please post your feedback as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `call` to run batch files from another batch file. Otherwise `cmd` won't return from the called one. So your code should read:

```
if exist "%check%\bin\versionInfo.bat" call "%check%\bin\versionInfo.bat" -maintenancePackages
echo %check%\bin\manageprofiles.bat
if exist "%check%\bin\manageprofiles.bat" call "%check%\bin\manageprofiles.bat" -listProfiles
goto :eof
```

(Also no need for a `:eof` jump label, you can just use the `goto :eof` special syntax to exit the batch file directly. I usually only use such a jump label if I need some cleanup to do first, but I name it differently then, to avoid confusion :-))

Comment: Oh, you figured that one out as well already. Ah well, I should read the comments ...